# exit(), quit() and sys.exit() not working in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm trying some exception messages using sys.exit() in Jupyter:

```
import sys
input_file=input("text file here:")

try:
    fhand=open(input_file)
except:
    print("there is no file such this one")
    sys.exit("exit file")
    
print(fhand)
```

but I'm getting some weird messages such as

```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

there is no file such this one
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-13-337dae3e5972>", line 6, in <module>
fhand=open(input_file)
```

When using exit() or quit() the line below the exception is printed and is having errors also.
This code works fine from the console, so it seems to be related to ipython and jupyter.

Any ideas here? Thanks!

Comment: Jupyter interacts with a Python interpreter. If you make that Python interpreter abruptly exit, the frontend is bound to get a bit confused.

Comment: Why would you try to use quit or exit in an interactive notebook? You can just close the notebook itself.

Comment: Better to not capture (all) exceptions and then exit yourself; just let the error bubble up, like a FileNotFoundError in your example. In fact, the file may exist (contrary to your error message), but the user may simply not have permission to open it; in which case your error message is incorrect, but Python will raise the appropriate exception.

Comment: Hi, what I wated to do is just dealing with the exeption so we don´t get a traceback and the program stops nicely, my first attempt was to use quit or exit, but the llines bewlow that one (either quit or exit) are still being executed. I read that sys.exit() maybe a better option..

Comment: Are you working in a Jupyter notebook? I wouldn't call that a program; you run the cells one by one, if there is an error, things stop. Furthermore, the traceback is useful, as you know what the problem actually is, and where it originates.

Answer (score 0):

Same as when an error happens in some package:

```
raise(ValueError)
```